# QR codes recognition solutions

Tags: .net, windows-8.1

I am need to recognize QR codes which an user have made by camera.  Is there any solution embedded in Windows 8.1? Or may be any .Net libraries working on Windows 8.1 (universal app) ?

I don't ask about algorithms, methodologies.  I'm interested in ready to use solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use ZXing.Net for my applications.  You can get it using NuGet or you can download from their CodePlex.

[zxingnet.codeplex.com](https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/)

---

As far I know they haven't expose the Bing Vision thing that decodes the QR Codes from the camera yet.